# How to get a row of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary indicating a list of directories and the number of contained files as below:

```
{
'path': [
  'folder0',
  'folder1',
  'folder2',
  'folder3'],
 'count': [
    '7',
    '21',
    '34',
    '56']
}
```

I'm going to iterate over this dictionary using for loop:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
```

This way, it assumes the keys are independent, so for each key, you have to iterate separately. But I would like to get access using an index so that when I call something like `dictionary[0]` the zeroth row of the table containing its path and the corresponding number(count) is returned. Is there any way?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why not change the structure of your dictionary? Something like `{'folder1': '7', . . . }`. Would be easier to navigate provided you don't have more than one reference value (like count).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I state that they are not optimal and could be improved.
But they do their job.

```
dict = {
'path': ['folder0','folder1','folder2','folder3'],
 'count': ['7','21','34','56']}

for key, value in dict.items():
    for ex in range(len(value)-len(list2)):
        list2.append([])
    for ind in value:
        list2[value.index(ind)].append(ind)

print(list2)
```

**OUTPUT**
`[['folder0', '7'], ['folder1', '21'], ['folder2', '34'], ['folder3', '56']]`

To print the various values instead you have to use:

```
print(list2[0][1])
```

Where the first index is that of the internal list and the second that of the element

**OUTPUT**
`7`

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
What about the value? I was looking for something like, in your example, return ('folder0', '7')

Comment: @MiladSikaroudi Ok now I change my answer

Comment: @MiladSikaroudi Did you mean that?